# how to extract one date only between two date provided in a column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this row called period which is a range of dates in a week. The period looks like this:

```
: 19 Oct to 25 Okt 2019
```

and I need to extract the second date only to be in a separated column called "event_date", so I expect the 25 Okt 2019 will be in my event_date column.

So far, what I have done was creating the period as new variable and I tried to split them as follow:

```
period = : 19 Oct to 25 Okt 2019
dt, _ = periode.split(' to ')
fmt = "%y%m%d"
date = datetime.strptime(dt, fmt)
df['event_date'] = date
```

but it did not work. How can I make it in python?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few corrections to spelling + imported the year:

```
period = '19 Oct to 25 Okt 2019'
dt, _ = period.split(' to ') 
dt = dt + ' ' + period[-4:]
fmt = "%d %b %Y"
date = datetime.strptime(dt, fmt)
df['event_date'] = date
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try replace `:` and characters `between Oct and 2019` using `regex` and convert outcome to `datetime`.

```
Data

print(df)
                   periode
0  : 19 Oct to 25 Okt 2019

df['event_date'] =pd.to_datetime(df['periode']\
.str.replace('(\:\s|\s\D{2}\s\d{2}\s\D{3})',''))

    periode                 event_date
0  : 19 Oct to 25 Okt 2019  2019-10-19
```

Comment: hi! thankyou, but actually I want to convert the second date which is 25 okt 2019, how can I do it?

Comment: `okt` is not a recognized datetime string. Conversion cant happen